# Firefox: Autoupdate from 4 to 5 on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, updates

I am using Firefox 4.01 on GNU/Linux x86_64.

Is there any reason why there is no autoupdate? In fact, when I look at the "About Firefox" dialog, it just says "Updates available at http://www.firefox.com/".

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: Install it manually <sub>(unless it comes with your Linux package management, thanks [Simon Sheehan](https://superuser.com/users/80670/simon-sheehan) for pointing that out)</sub>

---

First of all,

> Firefox 4's silent update will only be offered on Windows, Mozilla has said.<sup>[**1**](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9180272/Mozilla_plans_to_silently_update_Firefox)</sup>

however that applies only to security updates I suppose. That is backed up by the following statement:

> We are treating the automatic update checkbox enabled as a 'Yes, I want Mozilla to keep me updated. Previously as a courtesy we had people opt-in between major versions due to the potential jarring nature of the update. We feel the difference between 3.5 and 3.6 is not severe and with 3.5 reaching end-of-life 3.6 is the security update for 3.5 users. <sup>[**2**](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9216752/Mozilla_details_plans_to_kill_Firefox_3.5)</sup>

This has been the process for all major Firefox version before, as they're not an important Security Update per se but a **manual update** you can choose to make.

> On June 21, the day Firefox 5 is supposed to ship, Mozilla will automatically push Firefox 3.6.18 -- a standard security update -- if the company resolves a few remaining bugs. If those bugs don't get fixed by then, the auto-update will hit Firefox 3.5 users some time later.

So no mentioning of automatically updating the major version here as well.

Comment: If you are using a distro with a package manager, many such as ubuntu, Suse, Fedora, etc, should be shipping it via their package managers now.

Answer (score 0):

The auto update is only for minor releases 4.1 4.2

http://www.infoworld.com/t/browsers/mozilla-bring-auto-updating-firefox-174

> "We'll only be using the major update dialog box for changes like 4 to 4.5 or 5."